# ASP.NET MVC Get Route values from a URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I want to work out what the route values for the `UrlReferrer` in the controller action would be.

I can't figure out at what part in the MVC pipeline the incoming URL is converted into RouteValues, what I'm trying to achieve is close to that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need call `RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData` with a mocked `HttpContextBase` which returns your URL in its `Request`.

The routes are matched internally using the request's `AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath`.
However, this functionality is not exposed, so you need to pass an `HttpContextBase`.

You need to create an `HttpContextBase` class which returns an `HttpRequestBase` instance in its request property.
The `HttpRequestBase` class needs to return your path, beginning with `~/`, in its `AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath` property.

You don't need to implement any other properties, unless they're used by `IRouteConstraint`s.

Someone already wrote this: [Creating a RouteData instance from a URL](http://web.archive.org/web/20150223104725/http://www.scottschluer.com/creating-a-routedata-instance-from-a-url/)