# How can I parse a url into an action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET MVC Get Route values from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993990/asp-net-mvc-get-route-values-from-a-url)

One of my pages needs to determine from what action the current request came from. I can get `Request.UrlReferrer`, but need to translate this into an action and controller name. There's lots of ways to go from action to route, but how can I go back?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545432/how-to-get-routedata-by-url

Answer (score 1):

Here's your answer: [ASP.NET MVC Get Route values from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4994009/290343)